# How to Generate code with lambda notation using spring-roo

Tags: spring-roo

Currently I can not generate Lambda notation using spring-roo. It seems the antlr-javaparser that spring-roo use don't support lambda notations. Now how can i upgrade or replace the project from spring-roo. It seems if I change the project version it stop working.

Comment: Could you provide more info about the Spring Roo version that you're using? Regards

Comment: Create an issue in https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO and provide as much info as possible.